# Swift objects wrapped to Anyhashable if compiler optimalization is used

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8.2

I've run into an issue, that my swift objects are sometimes wrapped into `AnyHashable` when added to `Set`.

My class looks like this

`protocol ViewModelProtocol: MKAnnotation { ... }
class ViewModel: NSObject, ViewModelProtocol, MKAnnotation { ... } // don't know why compiler doesn't see this as redundant conformance to protocol`

My case is that I take an array of those protocols, cast it to `[MKAnnotation]` and pass it to *CCHMapClusterController* which saves it into a quadtree and then makes those annotations available via `NSSet` that is then bridged into `Set<AnyHashable>`.

Weird thing is that in development, when I take that `Set<AnyHashable>`, take the first object and conditionally cast it into `ViewModelProtocol` it succeeds. But in release configuration where compiler optimalizations are enabled (in development they are disabled) this cast fails because the element from the set is wrapped into AnyHashable so I have to take its base and cast that into `ViewModelProtocol`.

Has anyone experienced such a thing? I'm wondering why this stuff depends on compiler optimalizations?

I'm experiencing this behavior in Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: I cannot reproduce this – please could you provide a [mcve]? My *guess* is that it's a variant on the ["runtime dynamic casting doesn't bridge if necessary to bridge to a protocol" bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3871) ([this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42033735/2976878) might be related).

Comment: Looks like this was fixed in Xcode 8.3, I am unable to reproduce that anymore