# Downcast enum with Error protocol from Any type in Swift 4

Tags: swift

At this moment I want to try understand how Error protocol for enums working. It's a case where can happen with any developer who made normal architecture with request/response errors for logger or something else.

It's a simple in playground:

```
enum SomeError: String, Error {
    case myCustomError = "Printed Custom Error"
}

func prepareForSomething(sender: Any?) {

    if sender is Error {
        print ("is Error")
    }

    if let error = sender as? Error {
        doWithSomethingError(error)
    }

}

func doWithSomethingError(_ error: Error) {
    if let error = error as? SomeError {
        print (error.rawValue)
    }

}

prepareForSomething(sender: SomeError.myCustomError)
```

**Result:**

```
is Error 
Printed Custom Error
```

In this case we obtained the expected result

but when we try another one example, we have unexpected result

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SomeSegue", sender: SomeError.myCustomError)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SomeSegue" {

            if sender is SomeError {
                print ("is SomeError")
            }

            if sender is Error {
                print ("is Error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
is SomeError
```

As you can see, `Any?` type can downcast to assigned enum type with Error protocol, but not to original Error protocol.

So, the question is: why passed variable for `Any?` type do not working with overridden function `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` It's every day case where we can use this func and need to pass some data.

**UPDATE:**

I just tried to create another class and overridden function with similar `Any?` type but it's working fine.

I admit that this is a bug, but where I should report this I don't know.
Maybe I was wrong, but in face this should working.

Comment: This is a known bug, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/42033735/2976878

Comment: @Hamish Oh, it's more than one year ago, and don't fixed yet. Sadly. Thx for reply