# Downcasting from Any type to UIAccessibilityIdentification always failed

Tags: ios, swift, downcast

I tried to downcasting from Any type to UIAccessibilityIdentification but always failed

```
let button: Any = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
let accessIden = button as? UIAccessibilityIdentification
```

Result always nil.

I don't known the reason for this.

Can anyone explain?

Thanks,

Comment: Instead of `let button: Any = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)` use `let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)`

Comment: Yes. But i need cast from Any type. Can you explain why we can not cast from Any type. Do you have any solution if we need cast from Any type.

Comment: In that case you can use `let button: UIControl = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)`

Comment: You will need to go "via" a class; `if let control = button as? UIControl { let accessIden = control as? UIAccessibilityIdentification }`

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033735/failing-cast-in-swift-from-any-to-protocol

Answer (score 1):

You can check the list of `UI` elements [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilityidentification) that conforms to `UIAccessibilityIdentification`.

As  cast from `Any` to `UIAccessibilityIdentification` protocol is failed due to [this](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3871) bug in `Swift` so you first need to downcast to a known type that falls in the above list to `cast` as `UIAccessibilityIdentification`. For a `UIButton`, you can do it as below,

```
let b: Any = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
if let button = b as? UIButton, let acc = button as? UIAccessibilityIdentification  {
    print("Its a button")
}
```

Comment: Did you try `class ProtoCheck: NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
    }
}

let check: Any = ProtoCheck()
let checkDelegate = check as? UITableViewDelegate`. Any doesn't conform to `UITableViewDelegate` either, but in this case it works. So the reason you have provided in your answer is not correct.

Comment: @MidhunMP. You can check the `Swift` issue [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3871). In your example, the runtime is able to cast to `ProtoCheck` as probably it first tries to cast any as `AnyObject` and then ProtoCheck(check->AnyObject->ProtoCheck). In OP's case, it tries to cast any to protocol without trying the bridged type and fails.

Comment: I understand the issue, I'm concerned about this line `As Any is not in the list so you first need to downcast to a know type` in your answer, because it doesn't make any sense. The issue is related to class, structs & any type.